# Plotly chart "'Figure' object is not callable error" when displaying it on Streamlit page

Tags: python-3.x, charts, plotly, streamlit, figure

I have an issue with using Plotly and Streamlit together. The chart I've created works fine if I execute the code separately. But once I put the figure in `st.plotly_chart`, I get the `'Figure' object is not callable` error.

Here is the chart code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

d = {'Country': ['Portugal', 'Singapore', 'Norway', 'Mexico'], 
     'Rank': [33, 32, 30, 29],
     'Documents': [9950, 10154, 10892, 11073],
     'Citations': [110328, 134823, 176569, 103293],
     'H.index': [297, 349, 402, 289]
     }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

fig = px.scatter(x = pays_prod_moy['Citations'],
                  y = pays_prod_moy['Documents'],
                  size = pays_prod_moy['H.index'], 
                  color = pays_prod_moy['Rank'],
                  hover_name = pays_prod_moy['Country'], 
                  log_x=True, 
                  size_max=40,
                  color_continuous_scale='RdBu')
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_title="Average Documents",
    yaxis_title="Average Citations",
    coloraxis_colorbar_title="Rank"
)
st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```

I've seen that it can come from syntax, so I checked it but I have the same issue when I paste an example chart code from Plotly documentation. Both libraries have been just freshly installed. And it works with Altair charts.

Do you have any idea where does it come from and how to fix this?

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are working in. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to learn more.

Comment: Wild guess, but had you previously done something like `st.plotly_chart = fig`?  That would have overwritten the function instead of calling it.

Comment: In your post, `fig = px.scatter(...)` is indented, ie. `fig` is defined inside a code block and then used outside the block, so it's likely that the script doesn't enter this block and thus that `fig` is undefined when used after the block. But this is a speculation as the beginning of the block is missing, we would need to see more code. Also, you don't need to and should not use `fig.show()` when using `st.plotly_chart(fig)`.

Comment: @jasonharper I checked just in case, but no nothing like this.

Answer (score 0):

I've added `import streamlit as st`, renamed the dataframe to `pays_prod_mod` and it works.

Your code would be:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import streamlit as st

d = {'Country': ['Portugal', 'Singapore', 'Norway', 'Mexico'],
     'Rank': [33, 32, 30, 29],
     'Documents': [9950, 10154, 10892, 11073],
     'Citations': [110328, 134823, 176569, 103293],
     'H.index': [297, 349, 402, 289]
     }
pays_prod_moy = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

fig = px.scatter(x = pays_prod_moy['Citations'],
                 y = pays_prod_moy['Documents'],
                 size = pays_prod_moy['H.index'],
                 color = pays_prod_moy['Rank'],
                 hover_name = pays_prod_moy['Country'],
                 log_x=True,
                 size_max=40,
                 color_continuous_scale='RdBu')
fig.update_layout(xaxis_title="Average Documents",
                  yaxis_title="Average Citations",
                  coloraxis_colorbar_title="Rank"
                 )
st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```